# Имеет ли смысл использовать голый ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, веб-программирование

Имеет ли смысл использовать голый ASP.NET? Есть ли в этом какая-нибудь необходимость когда-нибудь?

Самое актуальное в .NET для создания Web App-это MVC?

Comment: что значит голый ASP.NET?

Comment: Например, без использования паттерна MVC

Comment: Почитал про MVC толком не понял использует мой ASP MVC или нет. Самописные контроллеры доступа в СУБД есть. Готовых MVC-библиотек не видел.

Comment: MVC это один из "принципов" написания программы на языке высокого уровня (в данном случае с#, ещё это называется паттерны или шаблоны проэктирования), кроме того для упрощения есть библиотека MVC которую можно использовать можно не использовать.

Comment: @nick_n_a когда говорят про asp.net и mvc вместе - обычно имеют в виду не общий MVC-паттерн, а одноименную библиотеку от Microsoft. И есть мнение, что там MVC существует только в названии :)

Comment: ASP.NET это всего лишь набор фреймворков, раньше это были WebForms, MVC и WebPages, сейчас, судя по https://github.com/aspnet , к нему можно и EF отнести. Так что понятие "голый тут не вполне уместно".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Голого ASP.NET" не существует. Существуют такие технологии, как ASP.NET WebForms, ASP.NET MVC и ASP.NET WebApi. Еще есть технология ASP.NET WebPages, основанная на движке Razor.

И под "голым ASP.NET" могут пониматься разные вещи.

### Вариант 1 - ASP.NET WebForms

Признаки WebForms - файлы с расширениями .aspx, .ashx, .asmx

WebForms появились исторически первыми, и по традиции иногда называются просто ASP.NET. Использовать их в новых проектах нет никакого смысла - они просто устарели.

### Вариант 2 - ASP.NET WebPages без ASP.NET MVC

Признаки WebPages - файлы с расширениями .cshtml

Обычно эти файлы "лежат" в папке Views и не могут открываться из браузера напрямую, вместо этого они вызываются из контроллера ASP.NET MVC. Но если их разместить за пределами папки Views - их можно будет открыть прямо из браузера!

*Ничего магического в названии папки Views нет - там просто по умолчанию валяется web.config, который запрещает обращаться к cshtml-файлам напрямую*

В некотором смысле, одиноко лежащий вне Views .cshtml-файл можно назвать "голым ASP.NET WebPages".  И такое решение вполне может иметь смысл - если надо по-быстрому отобразить динамическую страницу без особых заморочек наподобие того как это делают PHP или JSP.

### Вариант 3 - ASP.NET WebApi + статические файлы в веб-проекте ASP.NET MVC

Фактически, это два разных проекта (серверная и клиентская части), добавленные в пустой проект ASP.NET MVC для удобства разработки (как вариант - в два разных пустых проекта).

Так делать имеет смысл, поскольку пустой проект ASP.NET MVC предоставляет больше инструментальных возможностей, нежели пустой веб-проект или вин-сервис (вин-сервис даже не запустить без студии без дописывания отдельной "отладочной" ветки запуска в Main).

Но перед релизом лично я бы все же вынес ASP.NET WebApi в отдельный self-hosted вин-сервис.

### Вариант 4 - просто статический сайт под видом ASP.NET MVC-проекта

Так делать не очень умно, ASP.NET MVC статическому сайту не требуется.